# Aspnetboilerplate when published is very slow

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have created an Aspnetboilerplate application with Angular2.0 and .Net core. Deployed the application in server also but it is very slow, took almost 20 seconds to load the login page.

Used this command to build angular

> npm run ng build --env=prod

dist folder is 28 MB in size what will be the issue. Is there any software available to track the issue

Comment: check network speed in chrome dev console, check database speed with adding extra logs.

Comment: let me check it

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu vendor.bundle.js (4.4mb size taking 28 sec) and app.module.chunk.js(3.2mb taking 34.28 sec). how can i reduce the size

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu I am running into the exact same issue with AspNetZero .NET Core 2.0 MVC project. After I published it to my hosting site, its running much slower than it does on my desktop. Some button clcks work "normally" others there is a long delay before something happens. Is there anything I can check or do to make this better?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the size of bundles for sure.

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

1. Using the AoT compiler can help cut down your bundle size by over 50% and improve first paint by over 45%.
2. Tree shaking is the process of removing unused modules and code from your app before it is finally bundled and minified.
3. Angular Universal allows you to run your Angular App on the server.
4. Web Workers are great to offload your CPU intensive tasks to an independent web worker thread so that the frontend UI is not frozen or Janky when the app is fetching and processing large amounts of data. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2305
5. Service Workers. Checkout https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4006

**I strongly advice you to read these;**

- [Read The 4 Stages of Perf Tuning for your Angular2 App](https://medium.com/@areai51/the-4-stages-of-perf-tuning-for-your-angular2-app-922ce5c1b294)
- [Angular Performance Checklist](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist)